# Netsuite CSV import(An unexpected error has occurred)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Below is the sample code, i am using in CSV Import process.

```
   var createJob = nlapiCreateCSVImport();
   createJob.setMapping("CUSTIMPORTcust_pay");
   createJob.setPrimaryFile("Data_string");
   createJob.setOption("jobName", "Test imports");                                                                                                                                                        
   var JobId = nlapiSubmitCSVImport(createJob);
```

nlapiSubmitCSVImport function is returning JobId without any error, but in job status page[UI] it showing **status** is failed and in **Message** field it showing "An unexpected error has occurred", CSV Response field also empty. when i try this by running the above code with same data again, some time it is successfully imported and some time it got failed, with showing message "An unexpected error has occurred"

Comment: What kind of record are you importing? Is your import an insert, update, or upsert? Have you tried running the csv import through the UI to see if you get the same results?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [`setPrimaryFile(file)`](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3084719.html#bridgehead_N3085236).

Where file is either:

> The internal ID, as shown in the file cabinet, of the CSV file containing data to be imported, referenced by nlapiLoadFile. For example:
>   `.setPrimaryFile(nlapiLoadFile(73))`
>
> Raw string of the data to be imported.

You are passing in a raw string of `"Data_string"`.